# Array $field_instance is occassionally empty

Tags: entities

I am trying to determine why, on certain nodes, my address fields are not geocoded to my geofield. I think I have it tracked down to this part of geocoder.widget.inc (line 347).

```
function geocoder_widget_get_entity_field_value($entity_type, $field_instance, $entity) {
    $field_name = is_array($field_instance['widget']['settings']['geocoder_field']) ? reset($field_instance['widget']['settings']['geocoder_field']) : $field_instance['widget']['settings']['geocoder_field'];
```

If I add `dpm($field_instance)`, on one node update, it will show me that array. On a different node update, there is no devel message (i.e. no array). Both nodes have addresses.

The problem is, I cannot figure out why one would be blank while the other would not be.

Comment: Presumably you are using a service for the geocoding. There can be a number of reasons why a result is not returned but the commonest ones are exceeding query limits and address not recognised. Look for messages from the service in recent log messages.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was an issue with the manual lat/lon override. I didn't have it checked to allow it, but when I did check it and edited the problem nodes, the override box was already checked. Unchecking it then allowed my address field to be geocoded.